# Get mail attachment information with Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

How can I get mail attachment information with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/), having an Exchange object already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a maven project, you can use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

and then if you already have an Exchange object, you can try this:

```
Message message = exchange.getIn();
    if (message.getAttachments().size() > 0) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataHandler> entry : messageCopy.getAttachments().entrySet()) {
            DataHandler dataHandler = entry.getValue();
            //get the document filename                
            String attchmentFilename = dataHandler.getName();
            String decodedFilename = MimeUtility.decodeText(attchmentFilename);
            //get inputstream of attachment file
            InputStream is = dataHandler.getInputStream();              
            //generic function for extracting attachment content
            extractor(is);
        }
    }
```

I suggest to use Apache Tika inside extractor function for obtaining attachment content and other information